# How to split multiple lines in a cell

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to write a program that will allow me to read Excel files using C#.

These Excel files can contain information that has been entered with the use of "Alt-Enter" to create multiple lines within the cell. Each line denotes a different value.

How do I separate out the multiple values in the single cell?

[image: Here's what my data looks]

Comment: put your code what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Sample program:

Add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop`

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string path          = "C:\\Test.xlsx ";
Application excel    = new Application();
Workbook wb          = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet;

// Read the second row second column cell
string test = excelSheet.Cells[2, 2].Value.ToString();
string splittedString = test.Split('\n');
```

Comment: Did you look at the image he posted? He wants to also parse the string into integers.

Comment: @UweKeim looking more like 'she' :P

Comment: please use "OP"  => Original Poster rather than he/she as StackOverflow does not include gender in discussion

Comment: yup :) but that's not important right now  :D  please help me resolve issue